# how to format XML code alphabetically in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have this xml code. I want it to be organized alphabetically with Command + alt + L.

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="150dp"
 android:scaleType="fitCenter"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view"
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
 android:layout_marginStart="32dp" android:layout_marginEnd="32dp" />
```

example

```
<ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="150dp"
 android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
 android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
 android:scaleType="fitCenter"
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: You can format the code any way you want, but alphabetical is NOT the standard on android. The standard is for the id (if present) to always be first, so you can easily find it.  Then comes layout width/height in that order.  Then any other parameters dealing with the layout (here the layout_constraint parameters, any padding/margin, etc).  Then any other options.  Basically android code prefers grouping by type, rather than grouping by alphabetical order.  Especially since with the use of namespaces you end up with alphabeticals by source which makes no sense at all.

Comment: So how could I get the result I want?

Answer (score 3):

If you're with Windows or Linux, press CRTL+ALT+S, got to -> Editor->Code Style, there is a dropdown Scheme...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3vxF.png
select the Default IDE and apply, back to your XML file and press CRTL+ALT+L, this should work, in case of Mac, i don't know yet.

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it was. It turns out that when creating a new project, the defacto IDE is in:SCHEME Project, it had to change it to Default.